# How to set a nuxt3 project in ssr mode?

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I have done a nuxt3 project and put that on an online hosting service and I have also setup a nodejs server for that in there and also created a nodejs application and then I have uploaded the whole of my project code in the directory of that app. And in the nuxt.config.ts I have set the target: 'server'; but there is still a problem that the project is not running in ssr mode.
I will thank to tell me how can I solve this and set the project in ssr mode.
Here is a sample of on of my website scripts that is not working in the ssr mode:

```
<script setup>
const {data: posters} = await useFetch('https://something.com/posters/')
</script>
```

Comment: Using nuxt and enabling SSR in nuxt.config.ts might not automatically enable the app to behave like an SSR app.To be an SSR application , there also a job for you to write the app to behave like an SSR. For example , if you use data fetching in Vue lifecycle hooks such as onMounted , that data fetching code will not run when the server renders the component.It only run on your browser since its an client lifecycle hook.So if you expect the data rendered as soon as the page renders in the browser , you need to write data fetching code outside Vue lifecycle hooks such as in the setup script tag.

Comment: @lwinmoehein I have updated my question by putting on of the scripts of my website that is not working in ssr mode. I will thank to tell me what is the problem here.

Comment: Is the url in the useFetch working?

Comment: How do you run your app?
It should be the following: 1. build+bundle with `npm run build`; 2. run `npm run preview`. Or manually via `node ./server/index.mjs` (working directory './output' from step 1)

Comment: @lwinmoehein yes there is no problem with that.

Comment: @Hartmut I have created a nodejs application in my hosting service and uploaded the whole of my nuxt project(except node_modules) in the directory of that app and in the terminal of my host I have run npm i command to install dependencies and creating node_modules folder and then in the terminal I have entered the commands of npm run build and nuxt start.But the project is not working in the ssr mode. Can you tell me to how to solve this please?